# Creating new lists with a consistent range of indexes from another list

Tags: python, ipython

Looking for help please creating new lists from a list of 100+ items.
I am able to copy the list and create new lists based on intervals, but I would like to create new lists based upon an ordered range of the respective indexes.
So I have in my iPython 'whos':

```
Variable / List / n=105 [0:105] items...
```

And I want to create:

```
list a --> that has items in the above[0:7]
list b --> that has items in the above[7:14]
list c --> that has items in the above[14:21]
```

The range is consistent for all 105 items.

I'm wondering if there is a built-in module or perhaps 3rd party (Collections?) that can do this. Or perhaps a @Generator expression...I'm not sure.

Comment: Can you show a simple example of what you input/what is the output? And will slicing not work?

Comment: I think probably slicing will work, however I wanted a solution in case the list was very large in future etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[items[k:k+7] for k in range(0,105,7)]
```

In general,

```
[items[k:k+m] for k in range(0,len(items),m)]
```

splits list *item* into sub lists of fixed length *m*

Comment: Excellent Terence, thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for and has split it up into the 15 lists I needed.